# Why can't send syslog events from remote client?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

i have my first question after years.

i configured a remote syslog to send events to my syslogs event.

now i want to resend this events to a siem via syslog but i can't.

I see some events in var/log/messages the are not sending to the siem

## ### end of the forwarding rule

Comment: $template Incoming-logs,"/datos/syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.*  ?Incoming-logs
#& ~

Comment: # An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
*.* @mysiem

Comment: I create a waf file in /etc/rsylog.d called waf.conf with the following data (replace the dns name)
module (load="imfile" PollingInterval="60"
# access log:
input(type="imfile" File="/datos/syslog/mydnsclientname/ASM.log" Tag="waf" Severity="info" Facility="local6")
But this is not working

Comment: To add additional information, please edit your question instead of posting it as a comment.